# Samba/cifs shares on Linux

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

I'm trying to setup 2 samba shares (actual Linux permissions on them are 777):

1. Volume_1 (cifs username is firstUser)
2. Volume_1/someSubDir (cifs username is secondUser)

I get this error when second user tries to access Volume_1/someSubDir:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

Is this how samba supposed to work?

Does secondUser username has to be added to Volume_1 access list also?

Is there a way to give all users access to Volume_1 and restrict access to Volume_1/someSubDir?

works:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=firstUser,password=firstUserPassword,_netdev,noatime //192.168.10.199/Volume_1 /media/Volume_1
```

Doesn't:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=secondUser,password=secondUserPassword,_netdev,noatime //192.168.10.199/Volume_1/someSubDir /media/someSubDir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba share names are not related to the shared directory's path, and they always are a *single* path component.

When you mount `//server/Volume_1/someSubDir`, the share name is **`Volume_1`**, and `/someSubDir` is merely a subdirectory in that share.

If you want to use different permissions for `someSubDir`, you will have to pick a different share name, for example, "`Volume_1 subdir`".

Comment: "they always are a single path component." - Perfect. Thank you. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `smbpasswd` to set the Samba password for those users?

Comment: well.; I did it through the web interface, but I think it uses smbpasswd anyway. smbpasswd file contains hashes for both users.